# bootstrap carousel showing its whole content at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to build a carousel, I've copy-pasted a template but it never worked. It shows the whole content. There are four pictures and they are shown on top of each other.

I'm using bootstrap **v4**.

Here is the code :

```
<!-- Hot content & Social Network -->
     <div class="row">
   <div id="HotContentCarousel" class="col-sm-6 carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#HotContentCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#HotContentCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#HotContentCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
         <li data-target="#HotContentCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="picture1">
         </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="picture2">
         </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="img/pic3.jpg" alt="picture3">
         </div>
         <div class="item">
            <img src="img/pic4.jpg" alt="picture4">
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#HotContentCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#HotContentCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
   </div>
   <!-- END carousel -->
   <!-- Social Networks -->
   <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the file tree of my website (current is main.html) :

```
.
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   └── style.css
├── img
│   ├── pic1.jpg
│   ├── pic2.jpg
│   ├── pic3.jpg
│   └── pic4.jpg
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── jquery.min.js
│   ├── npm.js
│   ├── octicons
│   │   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   │   ├── octicons.css
│   │   ├── octicons.eot
│   │   ├── octicons.less
│   │   ├── octicons-local.ttf
│   │   ├── octicons.scss
│   │   ├── octicons.svg
│   │   ├── octicons.ttf
│   │   ├── octicons.woff
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   └── sprockets-octicons.scss
│   └── umd
│       ├── alert.js
│       ├── button.js
│       ├── carousel.js
│       ├── collapse.js
│       ├── dropdown.js
│       ├── modal.js
│       ├── popover.js
│       ├── scrollspy.js
│       ├── tab.js
│       ├── tooltip.js
│       └── util.js
├── main.html
└── nohup.out
```

Comment: Checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)
 bootstrap.min.js:7:2417
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
Uhm, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't copied the right template.
It shoud be `<div class="carousel-item">`.

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guruwanabe/5c5yta04/

Comment: That's not that, I've found working code with just class="item"
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel

Comment: check http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/, the template from the tutorialrepublic.com is from boostrap 3.3.6

Comment: Ok, I messed up between the versions, that was my problem, thanks.